# Storing handlers wrapped by boost::strand in array

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to store some event handlers in array. Some of them are wrapped by `boost::strand::wrap`.

```
boost::function<void(Request &)> proc_handlers[] = {
    boost::bind(&Service::req_proc_start, this, _1),
    m_strand.wrap(boost::bind(&Service::req_proc_start, this, _1))
};
```

As a result, I'm getting a bunch of errors like

> /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:35: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1) (ucb::Service*&, const ucb::Request&)’
>            unwrapper::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
>
> /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:35: error: binding ‘const ucb::Request’ to reference of type ‘ucb::Request&’ discards qualifiers
>            unwrapper::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);

I'm confused, because as mentioned in boost documentation [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html), `wrap` returns function object with the same signature as passed one have, so I assumed that it can be treated like other `boost::funcions` created by bind.

**Edit:** tried to post all gcc output [here](https://justpaste.it/6az7x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is deeply confusing and I feel your pain. I have fallen into the same trap myself.

The ASIO docs need some drastic improvement.

The confusing bit is here:

> Return Value
>
> A function object that, when invoked, passes the wrapped handler to the strand's dispatch function. Given a function object with the signature:

Note that in ASIO, "invoking" a handler is *not the same* as simply calling it.

The wrapped handler in my view really should not have an `operator()` at all, because calling that does not dispatch the handler to the strand. It merely calls the function.

Again here:

> that, when invoked, executes code equivalent to:

invoked does not mean "as if invoked with `std::invoke`"

The wrapped handler is not a function object as you would think of it. The reason it won't fit into a `std::function` is because its call operator is not `const`. This is fortunate in your case because if you hadn't had this error, you'd certainly have a race condition in your code.

How to fix?

I'm afraid you'll have to look at the boost source code to figure out how to invoke a handler properly. It's undocumented.

### correction.

When I say "undocumented", of course I mean "sparsely documented":

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html

Note that there is no narrative whatsoever on how to generate the 'handler' or get a pointer to it. The source code is your best bet.

### workaround

Store lambdas in your handler functions. The one that needs to dispatch via the strand will simply have to call `this->m_strand.dispatch(...)`

Comment: Yeah, the first thing i thought about was the suggested workaround. I guess it's the easiest way to go.

Comment: if it would fit in a `std::function<>` everybody would be filing right into the gigantic pitfall of erasing handler-type and actually **breaking** handler_invoke in doing so

Comment: `asio_handler_invoke` is pretty well treated by TannerSansbury on this site and there's a splendid "tie-it-all-together for `io_context` API" document here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html

Comment: @sehe thanks for the link. Very helpful. I still think that the wrapped handler should not have an operator() *at all*. It seems to me to be an interface that lies. When I mentioned this to Chris Kholhof during an email conversation, he never spoke to me again :)

Comment: I too doubt design choices around this spot. Things will get *hugely* less painful, I believe with executors, because you might split a handler into a tuple(calleable, executor) which you _can_ store. But I'm not sure whether all my expectations there are correct yet

Comment: @sehe ...just reading through the example in the link... it's hideous. In the light of c++17 it must be possible to construct a much more sensible api for service implementors.

Comment: The example includes everything and the kitchen sink. And i think it's more focused on teaching the fundamentals than style (although it would be nice if Asio adopted the `handler_pointer<>` utility)

Comment: Oh and another final point, that documentation maintains compatibility with both the old customization interface and the new (associated executors/allocators)